# Magento2 reindexing

Tags: magento2, reindex

I want to know how reindexing works in Magento2. I am wondering what affects in my database when we do reindexing in Magento2.

Can anyone help me in this please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

indexer:info              ==>                Shows allowed Indexers
indexer:reindex           ==>                 Reindexes Data
indexer:reset             ==>                Resets indexer status to invalid
indexer:set-mode          ==>               Sets index mode type
indexer:show-mode         ==>                 Shows Index Mode
indexer:status            ==>                Shows status of Indexer

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this to get proper knowledge of Indexing in Magento 2
[Click here](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/index-in-magento-2/)

Topics in this blog covers:

**Indexing Types**

**Index Status**

**Indexing Modes**

**Materialized View**

**Indexers**

**Custom Index in Magento 2**

**Manage Magento 2 Indexers** and many more

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the issues that are occurring when re indexing your magento .

Comment: I am not getting any issues. I want to get in-depth knowledge of reindexing in magento. 1. Why reindexing is introduced in Magento. 2. What happens in database when we do reindex. etc etc

Comment: In Short, If you see the database we will see the indexers tables there. When we use the indexer then it updates the data there and shows us at the front.

Comment: I see there are some tables ending with "_replica". When i run the indexing, the data seems to update in "_replica" tables. Is that correct ?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the tables, so I can check